i have problem in transform in css classes
enter image description here I defined two classes in that have different values but act the same
That is, both of them rotate upwards if one is -1 and the other is 1
.c1 {
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 180deg); 
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.d1 {
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: rotate3d(-1, 1, 0, 180deg); 
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

type here
fixed code :


.a1 {
  animation: 2s ease-in left1;
}
.b1 {
  animation: 2s ease-in right1;
}
@keyframes top1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 180deg);
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  }
}
@keyframes bottom1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 180deg);
    transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  }
}




I am not understanding what the problem is, could you make your code into a runnable snippet, using <> in edit, so we can see for ourselves.

https://codepen.io/Ebrahimi9999/pen/mdYyVWw

Code in the question please. (The problem with external sites is that they disappear, making the question useless for future readers).

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example With the emphasis on the minimal.

does transition: all 2s linear; in place of transition-duration help you?

Unfortunately no
You see, I want it to rotate in 3 directions on all 4 geographic directions of my figure that was clicked.
All the settings are correct, but the animations are done only in the shape of a round clock
I want one to be clockwise and one to be counter clockwise

So where are you transforming them to? And what causes the transform? Those two rotations do not do the same things.

I fix it
visit my code in question

Please create a runnable snippet. That means there needs to be some HTML as well. And please check by running the snippet yourself that it does actually show the problem.
